# Hyperledger fabric with node gives me You've asked to invoke a function that does not exist

Tags: node.js, typescript, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I created a chaincode in hyperledger fabric using the "first-network" as a local blockchain to deploy my contract, I tested it, it worked great, loved it, and then I decided to add a new method to my contract, nothing complex, a simple query.

My program is in node with typescript, so I deleted the dist folder, run `npm run build` and the `./byfn.sh down` script even deleted all my containers and images and started all back using the `./byfn.sh up` script and no matter what've tried I'm getting this error:

```
You've asked to invoke a function that does not exist: queryTransference
Failed to submit transaction: Error: Endorsement has failed
```

So I thougth maybe I'm doing something wrong, so I added my methods to the fabcar.ts example and started the fabric again to run the fabcar with both the fabcar methods and mine, and this time, I'm getting the same error for all my methods, while the original methods from the fabcar example are the only ones recognized.

So, where is fabric storing the old versions of the code? I'm deleting all dist folder, node_modules, containers and images, how come it doesn't update the contract if I'm publishing in a brand new blockchain? do I need to increase versions even in development each time I change something?

Thanks

Comment: The safest approach whenever you change your contract is to increment the version of the chaincode when you install and upgrade. If you are developing a contract then you should look at using developer mode described here https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/peer-chaincode-devmode.html or perhaps investigate the ibm blockchain extension for visual studio code to help develop your application.

Comment: Try deleting docker volumes once as there are times when these volumes creates confusion as they store the chaincode packages or other crypto-materials of the previous network configuration. So its a good practice to clear up your docker volumes when you are creating a fresh network. And if you are developing chaincode then either change the name for instantiating a new chaincode or if you are upgrading then increment the version of chaincode.